# Is there an angular directive that can restrict scope for an element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I was just wondering if there is some built-in angular directive (ng-some-directive) that allows you to restrict the scope to a particular model for the desired DOM element.

I belive I have seen something similar done before, but maybe I am thinking of knockout.js

```
<script>
    angular.module('example', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.heading = 'Some Value';
        $scope.complexModel = {...}
     }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
    <div ng-some-directive='complexModel.to.long.really.annoying'>
        <input type='text' ng-model='variable' /> // Actually coming from complexModel.to.long.really.annoying.variable
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a drastically simplified version

Answer (score 2):

Though its not meant for it

```
<div ng-init='sn = complexModel.to.long.really.annoying'>
        <input type='text' ng-model='sn' />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't recommend this use for `ng-init`.  `ng-init` is a directive with a priority greater than 0 to allow it to run after certain other higher priority actions have completed.  because it doesn't operate at priority 0, it is possible that you may rely upon the value being set and take action, only to find that the value isn't what you expect.  This is the core reason that `ng-init` is documented as only being appropriate for aliasing `ng-repeat` properties that aren't affected by priority.

Comment: I assume this means there is no provided mechanism to achieve this within angularjs. This was more of a request to try and keep my view code as clean as possible, but it isn't a "must have" feature, thank you Claies and @potatopeelings